# Comunicacion con servicio WCF en un dominio diferente

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, net, certificado

Tengo un servicio WCF hosteado en un servicio windows por protocolo TCP.
El servicio funciona bien cuando lo consumo desde otra maquina en el mismo domino, pero ahora lo nevesito consumir desde una maquina que no esta en el dominio, al conectarme me genera problemas de autenticacion, he estado leyendo acerca del tema y mas o menos entiendo que toca generar unos certificados....
Pero no he podido generar los certificados, ni realizar la configuracion correspondientes en el Back como en el cliente para poder realizar el consumo.
La verdad no he podido generar los archivos, si es posible su ayuda con alguna ayuda acerca de como generar estos certificados y de como configurar el servicio.

En este link se hace una descripcion de la creacion de los certificados:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/wcf-message-security-using-certificates/

Pero al momento de generar los certificados falla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco su ayuda con mis inquietudes.

El service model del cliente es este:

```
        <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding
            name="NetTcpBinding_IServicioCopiadoEnvio"
            transferMode="Streamed"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://xxx.xxx.x.x:520/TcpBackService" binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IServicioCopiadoEnvio"
          contract="ServicioCopiado.IServicioCopiadoEnvio" name="NetTcpBinding_IServicioCopiadoEnvio">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="xxxx\xxx" />
          <dns />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

El service model del back es este:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default"/>
    <services>
      <service name="ServicioCopiadoEnvio.ServicioCopiadoEnvio" behaviorConfiguration="BackEndServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:520/TcpBackService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ServicioCopiadoEnvio.IServicioCopiadoEnvio" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding_IServicioCopiadoEnvio"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBinding_IServicioCopiadoEnvio"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="Streamed"
                 closeTimeout="00:02:00"
                 openTimeout="00:02:00"
                 receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
                 sendTimeout="01:00:00"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard">
          <readerQuotas
            maxDepth="2147483647"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BackEndServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Hola! ¿Cómo intentaste generar / instalar(configurar) los certificados? ¿Cómo intentaste configurar el cliente del servicio? Edita tu pregunta y añade (como texto) esta información para que todos acá puedan ayudarte más rápido y fácil. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola el protocolo TCP es para que tu servicio este dentro de la misma red, sino tienen que abrir puertos en el firewall que no se aconseja, lo que podes hacer es usar otro Binding Https para tener seguridad igual que TCP.